# CSS link hover - how to expand area that changes colour upon hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/658epj15/

```
.navChild:hover{
    background-color:#626262;
}
```

When I hover over a link, the word has a background around it that illuminates, that is the length of the word.

How can I extend this so that it illuminates over the whole `<td>` and not just the div, so it illuminates from the left border of the `<td>` to the right border of the `<td>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tr td` instead of `.navChild`

```
tr td:hover {
  background-color: #626262;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/658epj15/2/

**Update, regarding to your comment:**
Pay attention to the following lines

```
tr td:hover, .current {
  background-color: #626262;
}
```

and

```
<td class="current"><a class="navChild" href=b illboard.html>Nav 1</a></td>
```

```css
.navParent table {
  color: #ffffff;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.navParent table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

.navParent table td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.navParent a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navChild {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

tr td:hover,
.current {
  background-color: #626262;
}
```

```html
<div class="navParent">
  <nav>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="current"><a class="navChild" href=b illboard.html>Nav 1</a></td>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=a bout.html>Nav 2</a></td>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=l ocations.html>Nav 3</a></td>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=p ricing.html>Nav 4</a></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works a treat. Could I ask as an add-on question, say I wanted the current page to have a constant background on it's appropriate link, say Nav 1, how would I do this? I can't seem to individually select it and give it a background color.

Comment: @SteveJobs You can locate the active site via PHP and insert a class to the td which does the same as the hover function

Comment: I see. PHP isn't my strong point, so could you provide an example of this, or an example of an alternative? I don't see why if I give the Nav 2 entry a class of `class = "current"` and then do `tr td .current{
 background-color: #ffffff;
}` it doesn't work

Comment: @SteveJobs Do you see where to put?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding hover on `a` add hover on `td`

```css
.navParent table{
  color:#ffffff;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
  }
.navParent table td{
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
 }
.navParent table td:first-child{
  border-left:none;
 }
.navParent a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:black;
}
.navChild
{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;

}
.navParent td:hover{
 background-color:#626262;
}
```

```html
<div class = "navParent">
  <nav>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><a class = "navChild" href = billboard.html>Nav 1</a></td>
    <td><a class = "navChild" href = about.html>Nav 2</a></td>
    <td><a class = "navChild" href = locations.html>Nav 3</a></td>
    <td><a class = "navChild" href = pricing.html>Nav 4</a></td>

   </tr>
  </table>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to display the a as a block element so it takes up the space of the cell that it is in. Also, you want to set the cellpadding on the table to 0 to eliminate the spacing around the text (you said you wanted it go border to border). This updated fiddle also fixes some incorrect HTML in the original (the closing table tag was wrong). https://jsfiddle.net/658epj15/3/

```
.navParent table {
  color: #ffffff;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.navParent table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

.navParent table td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.navParent a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navChild {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.navChild:hover {
  background-color: #626262;
}

<div class="navParent">
  <nav>
    <table cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=billboard.html>Nav 1</a></td>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=about.html>Nav 2</a></td>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=locations.html>Nav 3</a></td>
        <td><a class="navChild" href=pricing.html>Nav 4</a></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, your `<a>` tags are set to `display: inline`, and won't fill out the `<td>`. Set them to `display: block`, and the hover should work as expected.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/658epj15/1/).